# Getting x and y axis with arrows in matplotlib and controlling position of x and y-labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi the plot given here https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axisline_style.html

has labels on y-axis on the right-hand side of y-axis, but I want them to be on the left-hand side of y-axis. How do I do it?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

if 1:
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    ax.axhline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")
    ax.axvline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")

    plt.xticks(range(11))

    ax.text(0, 1.05, 'y', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes), ha='center')
    ax.text(1.05, 0, 'x', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transAxes, ax.transData), va='center')

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    ax.axis["yzero"].set_visible(False)

    for direction in ["right", "top"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    plt.yticks(range(11))
    plt.grid(True)

    plt.show()
```

This code block gives me that. But the arrow from y-axis is missing.

Comment: Note that the code you used (taken from the matplotlib doc pages, so not your fault) is not great. It is out of date: `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero` generates a `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning` since matplotlib version 2.1 (released in 2017). Also, `if 1:` is poor Python (it should be `if True:` at a minimum, or rather scrapped entirely). It works, but do not take it as an example!

Comment: @Leporello The current version of this example is [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html), and it uses `from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added 2 lines in your code. Hope it helps.

1. added to invert the label from right to left.

   ```
   ax.axis["yzero"].invert_ticklabel_direction()
   ```
2. set 'left' to be invisible

   ```
   for direction in ["left", "right", "top"]:
   ```

Updated in your code:

```
    from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
    from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy

    if 1:
        fig = plt.figure(1)
        ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
        fig.add_subplot(ax)

        ax.axhline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")
        ax.axvline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")

        plt.xticks(range(11))

        ax.text(0, 1.05, 'y', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes), ha='center')
        ax.text(1.05, 0, 'x', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transAxes, ax.transData), va='center')

        for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
            ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
            ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

        # added to invert the label from right to left.
        ax.axis["yzero"].invert_ticklabel_direction()

        # set 'left' to be invisible
        for direction in ["left", "right", "top"]:  # for direction in ["right", "top"]:
            ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

        plt.yticks(range(11))
        plt.grid(True)

        plt.show()
```

Comment: Even better would be to include `"bottom"` as well in the list of spines that are invisible.